# Loading an Image in an Applet without getImage()?

Tags: java, image, file, applet, load

I usually load images in Applets using:

```
this.getImage( getCodeBase(), "myimage.png" );
```

or

```
myapplet.getImage( getCodeBase(), "myimage.png" );
```

But what if I want to load an image from another class which is not a child of Applet, neither does it have a member which refers to the Applet?

Say, I have a sprite class, in whose `update` method I want to load images for animation:

```
@Override
public void update(){

    frame++;
    if ( frame > 3 ) frame = 1;

            /* the problem */
            loadImage( getCodeBase(), "myimage_" + frame + ".png" ); 
}
```

Of course I could include `Applet app` as parameter, but the sprite's update method gets called in so many different parts of the code and in so many other classes, that it will extremely complicate stuff and make life difficult.

So is there a way I can load an image from a file in an applet **without** using the applet's `getImage()` method?

Comment: The issue seems to be 'how to form the URL' rather than 'how to avoid getImage()'.

Comment: people seem to ignore java questions nowadays... :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> So is there a way I can load an image from a file in an applet without using the applet's getImage() method?

```
Image img = ImageIO.read(url);
```

Answer (score 0):

When loading an image from a file in a non-applet class definition or in an application, you need the following statements:

```
Toolkit toolkit = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit();
Image image1 = toolkit.getImage("fileName.ext");
```